# Regex get certain information

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I've stumbled with certain types of rows.

I parse this information
`195/75 R 16 C X Wonder Van 110/108R 10PR Tourador`
[The groups, which I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXY8O.png)

I've got the following regex

```
([0-9]+)?\/([0-9]+)\s*\w\s*([0-9]+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(C\s+)?(.+\s+?(?=[0-9]{2,3}|(\d{2,3}\/\d{2,3})))(?:(\d{2,3}\/\d{2,3})|(\d{2,3}))\s*(\w)(.*)
```

It works nicely for all kinds od rows, e.g

> 225/55 R18 X Speed TU1 98V Toradfor 
> 225/50 R 16  X Wonder TH1 96W XL Tourador 
> 195/75 R 16 C X Wonder Van 110/108R 8PR Tourador

However, it doesn't work  for

> 195/75 R 16 C X Wonder Van 110/108R 10PR Tourador
> because of `10PR`, where 10 consists of 2 digits
> [how it works now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnarM.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In you pattern you use alternations `|` that can match and capture unrelated parts in the strings.

What you could do is use anchors and and an optional capture group

For all the given example strings you might use:

```
^(\d+)\/(\d+)\s+[A-Z]*\s*(\d+)\s*([A-Z])(.*?)(\d+\/\d+([A-Z]+))?\s+(\d+[A-Z]+\s+.*)$
```

The pattern in parts:

- `^` Start of string
- `(\d+)\/(\d+)\s+` Capture 2 times 1+ digits in a group
- `[A-Z]*\s*` Match optional chars A-Z and optional whitspace chars
- `(\d+)\s*` Capture 1+ digits in a group and match optional whitespace chars
- `([A-Z])` Capture a single char A-Z in a group
- `(.*?)` Capture as few as possible chars in a group
- `(` Capture group

  - `\d+\/\d+` Match 1+ digits `/` and 1+ digits
  - `([A-Z]+)` Capture 1+ chars A-Z
- `)?` Close the capture group and make it optional
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(\d+[A-Z]+\s+.*)` Capture group, match 1+ digits, 1+ chars A-Z, 1+ whitespce chars and the rest of the line
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/54avjI/1)

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work for this kind of rows:

`235/45 R 18 ProTech NewGen 98Y XL FR Viking`

`195/65 R 16 C TransTech II 104/102T Viking`
`315/35 R 20 Observe GSi6 Suv 110V XL TL Toyo`

`245/40 R 18.5 OBSERVE G3-ICE 97T Toyo`

Comment: @S.Solomon Can you update this example https://regex101.com/r/yBLwmU/1 with the expected groups/ matches as these are different example string.